# Override browserify require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I want to override browserify's `require` function so that I can inject custom logic. My application runs across multiple iframes and need to return some objects from another context.

**How can I override browserify's `require` function?**

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if(Browserify){

  var oldRequire = Browserify.require;

  Browserify.prototype.require = function() {
     //My code
     //If I want use the original require 
     oldRequire.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version(s) of Browserify does this work for? I can't find the symbol locally..